# Happy Holidays; here's a Riley!

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge, acrostic

It's been a while since I've posted a riddle of any kind, and I figure I'll post an easy one. As always, good luck to all of you and I hope you enjoy it! Oh, and happy holidays!

> Jasmin, or juniper, the suffix is one.
>
> Obscured and unseen, until we are done.
>
> Next is the prefix, for summer's flowers.
>
> Exactly; eight chunks, of ninety-three hours.
>
> Summer the best time, in fact, just July; together made history, a season in time.

---

The correct answer will:

- Explain the acrostic.
- Explain each line but the second.
- Correctly answer the Riley.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Mayflower

Jasmin, or juniper, the suffix is one. 
Obscured and unseen, until we are done.

> Flower

Next is the prefix, for summer's flowers.
Exactly; eight chunks, of ninety-three hours.

> May - the length of the month is 744 hours

Summer the best time, in fact, just July; together made history, a season in time.

> The ship embarked in July 1620, transporting Pilgrims to the New World.

Acrostic

> The owner of the ship was Christopher JONES

Comment: For the "summer's flowers" line, I suspect that this has something to do with another famous rhyming line!